# Android Studio - Korlin Coroutines --> Unresolved references: async & launch

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning on Kotlin, and I'm in Coroutines.

I searched around the web, maybe the method i'm using is old? but i have async and launch(UI) aren't resolved...

my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}
...
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

the code to get data from api (UPDATED)

```
//getting data from api
fun fetchCharacterData(): Deferred<CharachterGenerator.CharacterData> {
    CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        
           async {   val apiData = URL(CHARACTER_DATA_API).readText()
               CharachterGenerator.fromApiData(apiData)
           }
    }
       return <--- how to get this correct, what should I return?
}
```

I use launch in a button setOnClickListener

```
generateButton.setOnClickListener {
            CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
            characterData = fetchCharacterData().await() 
            displayCharacterData()
            }
          }
        displayCharacterData()
    }
```

please bare with me I'm still learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`launch` and `async` are member functions of CoroutineScope. You can’t make bare calls to them unless you’re calling them from within a class that implements CoroutineScope. You may have seen this in the Kotlin documentation, but most of their examples are used within a `runBlocking` lambda, which provides a scope as function receiver. On Android, you typically will use the CorotuineScopes provided to you, like `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`.

**Edit after your update:**

A common pattern for a function that does something asynchronously and returns a result is not to return a Deferred, but to make it a suspend function that directly returns a result using `withContext`:

```
suspend fun fetchCharacterData() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val apiData = URL(CHARACTER_DATA_API).readText()
    CharachterGenerator.fromApiData(apiData)
}
```

Then when you call it your code is very simple because you don’t have to worry about what dispatcher you are on:

```
generateButton.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        characterData = fetchCharacterData()
        displayCharacterData()
    }
}
```

It is a mistake to use the `CoroutineScope()` constructor-like function to create a one-off scope that you aren’t storing in a property where you can manage its lifecycle. You should rarely need to create your own since Android provides `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` for you and manages their life cycles on your behalf.

Comment: I updated my answer. But it would have been better to open a new question than to change your original one because now it is no longer searchable by other people that might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After moving around on several other documentations I managed to do it this way

calling the API using async:

```
 fun fetchCharacterData(): Deferred<CharachterGenerator.CharacterData> {

    return CoroutineScope(IO).async  { val apiData = URL(CHARACTER_DATA_API).readText()
               CharachterGenerator.fromApiData(apiData)
           }
    }
```

making the request and getting the result then send it to be displayed

```
        generateButton.setOnClickListener {
            CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
                characterData = fetchCharacterData().await()
                displayCharacterData()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why change it from my answer? Using one-off `CoroutineScope`s is incorrect. If your Activity is closed while it's working, the Activity will be leaked. [Here's an article](https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055) by the lead developer of Kotlin coroutines where he specifically has an example of a function that does this and called it `doNotDoThis()`. There is no reason to create separate coroutine scopes and throw them away instead of using the existing `lifecycleScope`. It is also very weird to return a Deferred instead of simply making it a suspend function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 please don't take any offense... i tried to have them both checked and it seems that i only can check one... you are right about your point. the only thing is that i didn't find the android coroutines available in IntelliJ, and i wanted an answer for Kotlin only not android... anyway thank you for your comment and the link. i will mark your answer...

Comment: No offense taken. I just don’t want anyone led down the wrong path of using coroutines incorrectly. If you are not developing for Android, there are separate coroutine backends for Swing and JavaFX that provide the CoroutineScopes needed. And if you don’t have that, you should still set up your CoroutineScope in a property so you can cancel it at the appropriate place in your lifecycle.